# Как присвоить компоненту v-dialog свойство border-radius: 10px?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

По умолчанию в файле `vuetify.min.js` у *v-dialog* прописано `border-radius: 2px`, но если в CSS задать другое значение для свойства *border-radius* ничего не происходит.

---

Есть какие-то решения, не хотелось бы хардкодить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете решить свою задачу, используя класс элемента (в вашем случае `.v-dialog`) и свойство CSS [!important](http://htmlbook.ru/css/%21important).

Достаточно применить в вашем файле стилей такую запись:
`.v-dialog{border-radius:10px !important}`

Привожу пример для наглядности:

```css
.v-dialog{border-radius:10px !important}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@3.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-main>
        <v-container>
        <template>
            <div class="text-xs-center">
              <v-dialog
                v-model="dialog"
                width="800"
              >
                <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                  <v-btn
                    color="red lighten-2"
                    dark
                    v-on="on"
                  >
                    Открыть диалог
                  </v-btn>
                </template>

                <v-card>
                  <v-card-title
                    class="title grey lighten-2"
                    primary-title
                  >
                    Скругление уголков v-dialog на 10px
                  </v-card-title>

                  <v-card-text>
                     реализовано через CSS свойство border-radius ...
                  </v-card-text>

                  <v-divider></v-divider>

                  <v-card-actions>
                    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                    <v-btn
                      color="primary"
                      
                      @click="dialog = false"
                    >
                      OK
                    </v-btn>
                  </v-card-actions>
                </v-card>
              </v-dialog>
            </div>
          </template>
        </v-container>
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  </div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    new Vue({ 
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    data :{
        dialog: false
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```